# Prove $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{2}e^{-nx^2}dx = 0$ using Convergence Theorems

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that a) $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{2}e^{-nx^2}dx = 0$.

Show using convergence theorems.

I am using this post as a guide: [Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 e^{-nx^2}\, dx = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515939/prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-e-nx2-dx-0)

Did the posters there use convergence theorems? I am really new to the subject and need some help identifying which answers in that post apply to my situation.

Comment: What convergence theorems do you know?

Comment: I know that $\int f = \text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$. Do you think it would be appropriate to just swap to the $\int f$ verions and prove that $=0$? Does that count as "using convergence theorems" to you?

Comment: All those questions are about the required conditions to apply a given theorem. So you should look at which convergence theorem you want to apply, what are the required conditions and are those specific conditions fulfilled in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So perhpas the proof starting mid way though the first page of this: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-02-conv-thms.pdf would show me the conditions I need to check for?

Comment: You can do the same as Jack D'Aurizio but much simpler since $\exp(-nx^2)\le \exp(-n)$ for $x\in[1,2]$.

Comment: Both of you are awesome. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier than showing $\int_0^1 e^{-nx^2}\,dx \to 0.$ The function $nx^2$ increases on $[0,\infty),$ hence $-nx^2$ decreases there. Therefore $e^{-nx^2}$ decreases on $[0,\infty).$ It follows that

$$\int_1^2 e^{-nx^2}\,dx \le e^{-n\cdot 1^2}\cdot (2-1) = e^{-n}$$

for each $n.$ Since $e^{-n}\to 0,$ we're done.